# OIF versus OVP for new applications

Tags: abap, webdynpro

According to the Floorplan Manager for Web Dynpro ABAP Developer's Guide since at least version 7.0 EHP3, the Object Instance Floorplan (OIF) 'has been superseded by the Overview Page (OVP) floorplan' and it provides the additional recommendation that 'all new applications for object instances should be built using the OVP floorplan'.

I'm fairly new to OIF as it is and am about to start work on a large FPM application that will display various dynamic tables, text fields and input sections. Should I forget about OIF entirely and create an OVP application?

Are there certain caveats I should be aware of before beginning with OVP?

Or is creating an OIF application ill-advised considering the technology is now deprecated?

Comment: Why would you develop in depreciated technology unless you absolutely had to?

Comment: Maturity, familiarity, more readily available documentation and examples, faster development and a lower budget impact are some of the things I've considered. More important to me is the fact that the technology is almost entirely unknown to me and my colleagues along with the fact that I've been warned before against early adoption of the myriad of new technologies that SAP regularly releases and replaces. That's why I'd like to know if there are any particular issues with OVP replacing OIF.

Comment: For me, I would say those are perfectly good considerations when choosing newer vs older tech.  But when one of them is depreciated it adds another level that very, very strongly favors the newer tech.  Bugs may not be fixed in OIF, new functionality won't be added to OIF, etc.  Like I said, unless I absolutely had to I would not choose something SAP had depreciated.

That said, I haven't used OVP yet, so perhaps someone else will chime in.

Comment: To me WebDynpro is generally a tragic technology, so whether OIF or OVP, does not matter. Do not use WD at all. ;-)